# How can i change or remove title and page address?

Tags: html, css

I use some CSS styling to hide input buttton, images and so on but i wonder how can i remove or better: modify, where / what shows up on printed page in place of title and page address?

Comment: You should clarify that you're referring to printed pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the browser's standard header and footer, and cannot be controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't. Those headers and footers are added by the browser. You can usually remove them in the browser's "Print" settings, but there's no way to get rid of them globally for all users.